# routerLinkActive style overriden by angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button with an icon and span and when routerLinkActive is triggered I want to change the style. If I inspect the button element via the browser I see that the style is somehow overriden by angular material.

In an older project this has worked the way it's currently implemented.

```
<button mat-flat-button class="mobile-nav__btn" routerLink="/explore" routerLinkActive="mobile-nav__icon--active">
    <mat-icon style="margin: 0 auto 4px auto;" svgIcon="search-icon"></mat-icon>
    <span class="mobile-nav__span" translate="navbar.bottom.explore.label"></span>
</button>
```

```
.mobile-nav__icon--active {
  color: red;
}
```

Below you can see that it's override by '.mat-mdc-unelevated-button:not(:disabled)'

[image]

Comment: Is it an option to use `color: red !important;`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can try to set this CSS variable

```
    .mobile-nav__icon--active { 
      --mdc-filled-button-label-text-color: red;
     }
```

if this won't help then you can try to set it with !important at the end or Specify the color style explicitly (with important as well).